# How to determine the smtp server save send mails or not?

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail, imap

When sending mail using SMTP server, how to determine whether the smtp server rely and save send mails to "Sent" folder or not.

Example

When sending mail using GMail smtp server ( smtp.gmail.com ), GMail server automatically rely and save the mail to "Sent" folder. But few other server like Exchange, GoDaddy,.. these are the servers not saving the mail to "Sent" folder. We have to manually append the message to respective folder using IMAP append command.

If I able to find whether the server won't save send mails to "Sent" folder means, I can invoke IMAP append command to save the mail to "Sent" folder

Comment: You cannot; gmail is the only I know that does this.  Most email clients have an 'Append to Sent Folder' user option that can be turned off.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find that out. But you can make gmail and godaddy behave almost compatibly by sending a Bcc to the user. Gmail does that automatically, but if you do it explicitly the user still gets only one copy.

When you send mail via SMTP, add "rcpt to:<myaddress@doma.in>", and both gmail and godaddy will write the message to some filter. If you're lucky the message is even in the right folder.

Comment: Except bcc will appear in the users inbox, which is usually not the desired outcome.

Comment: The Bcc header is removed before the message is sent.  The addresses end up as additional "RCPT TO:" addresses, but not part of the message.

Comment: IIRC gmail writes the message to "sent" instead of the inbox when you send it on port 587 and add an RCPT TO yourself. Godaddy is another matter.