# is it possible to create filter from gmail api to label messages to sent folder

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, thunderbird

I tried to create filter from the api on SENT label

```js
//endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/settings/filters
{
  "criteria": {
    "from": "mygmail@gmail.com"// this is my current email. i planned to track all outbound emails that i sending from sendgrid and add them to sent folder as its not possible other wise.
  },
  "action": {
    "addLabelIds": [
      "SENT"
    ]
  }
}
```

but i am getting error when i try it on SENT label.
error:

```js
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidArgument",
    "message": "Invalid label: SENT"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid label: SENT"
 }
}
```

is there another way to do it ?
i need to find a way to send via sendgrid smtp and store the outbound emails in gmail sent folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can change label or labels of messages with their ids only.
so you must get all ids wich you sent message to "mygmail@gmail.com" and after this you can make a batch modification for all with one request .

you can try the gmail-api here [batchmodify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/batchModify)

Comment: hi thanks. i need something more efficient. 
i saw in other post someone said "IIRC gmail writes the message to "sent" instead of the inbox when you send it on port 587 and add an RCPT TO yourself. Godaddy is another matter. – arnt Jun 9 '15 at 20:56"(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729128/how-to-determine-the-smtp-server-save-send-mails-or-not)
how i can implement it if i send from sendgrid smtp.

Comment: google have make gmail-api with a specific parameters by default the sent message go have the label SENT and in his documentation there is no information for changing that (default label for sent message), for the topic with smtp i dont know exacly how it work sorry